# Change style of pseudo elements in angular

Tags: css, angular

In my CSS I have

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: red;
}

ol li:before {
  --number-prefix: 'Chapter ';
  content: var(--number-prefix) counter(item, decimal) '. ';
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

and my HTML I have below

```
<ol>
  <li [ngStyle]="{'--number-prefix': 'Module'}">Item 1</li>
  <li [ngStyle]="{'--number-prefix': 'Module'}">Item 2</li>
  <li [ngStyle]="{'--number-prefix': 'Module'}">Item 3</li>
  <li [ngStyle]="{'--number-prefix': 'Module'}">Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

My aim is to get the variable `--number-prefix` to be replaced with `Module` in my numbering. A user is to be able to define their own numbering style

The above approach produces

```
Chapter 1. Item 1
Chapter 2. Item 2
Chapter 3. Item 3
Chapter 4. Item 4
```

I expected the variable to be replaced and the result to be

```
Module 1. Item 1
Module 2. Item 2
...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Am using Angular 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles in pseudo-element override styles declared on element itself.

It means that you need to define variable on element level if you want it to be overrided by Angular.

```
ol li {
  --number-prefix: 'Chapter ';
}
```

Then, custom css properties are not supported in ngStyle syntax yet. You should be using style binding instead:

```
[style.--number-prefix]="'\'Module'"
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/ZLPnM6sfjPKxhPM5TX3Y)**

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your scenario with attribute property and it works fine. If you want to try this way. Please check this out.

```
 <li [attr.number-prefix]="'Module '">Item 1</li>
```

In css file

```
ol li:before {
  content: attr(number-prefix)  counter(item, decimal) '. ';
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nicely done though i have to accept @yurzui solution as it is more straight forward